# Is the SQLite good enough for statistics?

Tags: sqlite, statistics

Is 'Sqlite' appropriate for statistic?
I'd like to stack data on android and use trigger.
I might use join,union operation.

is there any another db (mongodb or graph db) and other languages or 
the sqlite is enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `R` for statistics with Sqlite. Given R is made for stats. Take a look at the `R` documentation for database support, http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-data.html#Overview-of-RDBMSs